# Question put on hold

Tags: discussion

Regarding my question [What movie displayed a self-destruct button next to a button for every day use?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81055/55643), how is it not asking for a specific movie?

I have not merely provided a single image. I gave a fair amount of detail in the question. It's not my fault that there may be many movies that have this trope (I didn't even know it was one).

What else should be present in my question that is missing in order for it to be considered on-topic?

Answer (score 6):

> how is it not asking for a specific movie?

Yes, it is asking about a specific movie since the questions says *What movie*.

> What else should be present in my question that is missing in order for it to be considered on-topic?

For starting, you can take a look at the Identify-This-X Questions section on [on-topic page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site in regards to identifying actors, movies, TV shows, and specific episodes of TV shows. ID questions must be as descriptive as possible and should not consist of only an image for detail. Important details to include are:
>
> 1. Plot details of any scenes you remember
> 2. Descriptions of any characters or locations
> 3. Where you watched the movie or TV show
> 4. When you watched the movie or TV show
> 5. Any idea of how old it was
> 6. Any idea of country of origin (if known)
> 7. Whether it was animated or not
> 8. **Any other distinctive detail**

Now coming to your question.

The question in question has no particular specific details except this,

> Which movie showed a ship self-destruct button on the wall right next to a button for trivial every-day use (something like a button to get coffee)?

which, in my opinion, is very common in movies. You didn't provide any other plot details, the time you watched it, any character specifications, or any other distinctive details. These details are necessary in order to identify a movie.

Kindly add these details and anything you remember about this movie, anything. After adding these details, your post will go through the Reopen Votes queue where community will decide whether it should be reopened or not.

And thanks for bringing this to meta.

Comment: I added as much detail as I can remember.

Comment: I see you have edited your post to include some more details. Good. However, it still lacks specific plot details.

Comment: How can you have a rule that is "include as much detail as you can remember" and then you pass judgement on insufficiency of someone else's memory !?!?

Comment: @TommyTommy We do edit those posts, but how are they gonna learn? And most of the users asking ID question never return to improve their posts.

Comment: @TommyTommy " just editing the post(s) yourselves to fit the "law"". Are you suggesting to add details to ID which even asker don't know, how is it possible?